# Is it possible to have interactive plots in Emacs?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, emacs, interactive, matplotlib-animation

I was trying to use Emacs as my editor for my research (I followed all steps in Jon Fincher’s guide on Realpython : [https://realpython.com/emacs-the-best-python-editor/]).

I use jupyter notebooks a lot for data visualization, so I installed ein [https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook].
I can use my virtual environment in Emacs (pyvenv-workon), open my notebook run all the cells fine : until I launch a cell with a maptlotlib plot.

In jupyter to have an interactive plot I put « %matplotlib nbagg » in my code cell and it works just fine.
In Emacs it prints « <IPython.core.display.Javascript object » but it does not display it.
If I do « %matplotlib inline », it opens a .png file in my image viewer but I do not have the features of an interactive plot.

In an ideal world I would also like to be able to see a matplotlib anmation.

I browsed a bit and I think I understood that Emacs could not work with Javascript objects, is that correct ? A possible workaround for me would be to have the *interactive* plot in a seperate window but I did not find how to do that, is there some wiki I missed ?

Cheers

· %matplotlib nbagg returns an interactive figure in jupyter notebook browser interface, seems not to work in Emacs.

· plt.ion() should give interactive access does nothing.

· %matplotlb inline opens a non-interactive .png file with the plot

Comment: That pretty much sums it up. It would not be impossible to build a similar facility in Emacs Lisp but I am not aware of any attempt to do so.

Comment: @tripleee thanks. Well that’s super sad then, no Emacs for me. I’ll stick to jupyterlab.

Comment: "A possible workaround for me would be to have the interactive plot in a separate window" -- if you mean it would be acceptable for a separate (not Emacs) GUI program to render the interactive graph, I don't see why you couldn't have that.  Emacs can certainly run other programs, so the main thing you need is something which knows how to render the kinds of "interactive plot" that you're generating.  As you're talking about Javascript, I suppose you want to run a web browser to do that.

Comment: Here's one example of Emacs talking to a web browser to display a fancy visualisation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H38Yglw1dU .  I don't use any of this stuff myself, so I'm afraid I have no specific pointers, but I wanted to clarify that this much would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late, however, others having similar issues can still hopefully make use of this.

For showing interactive matplotlib plots with Emacs (elpy package for python major mode), there are two methods which works (as far as I have tested):

**1.** One can set Qt as backend, `matplotlib.use("qtAgg")`, before calling the plot function.

Make sure pyqt5 is installed via `pip install pyqt5` in the python environment which is being used by the elpy.

Checked with:

- GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-07-31
- Elpy 1.35.0
- Jupyter console 6.6.3 (python-shell-interpreter variable in elpy-config set to jupyter)
- Python 3.11.4
- Matplotlib 3.8.3
- Pyqt5: PyQt5-Qt5-5.15.2, PyQt5-sip-12.13.0, pyqt5-5.15.10

**2.** Use `webAgg` as backend for the matplotlib. This requires no other packages, but opens a browser tab/window every time.

**MWE:**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

matplotlib.use("qtAgg")

plt.plot(np.random.normal(0,1,(10, 1)))
plt.show()
```